# Не открывается div

Tags: javascript

Только начинаю познавать JS, поэтому хотел спросить.
Имеется код, который должен при нажатии кнопки раскрывать блок текста. Но у меня почему то он не работает. В чем ошибка?

```js
let coll = document.getElementsByClassName('content');
for (let index = 0; index < coll.length; index++) {
  coll[index].addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.classList.toggle('active');
    let content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.maxHeight) {
      content.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + 'px'
    }

  })
}
```

```css
.collapsible {
  background-color: #777;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.active,
.collapsible:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}

.content {
  padding: 0 18px;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<button class="collapsible">Open block</button>
<div class="content">

  Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quo optio illo quod enim suscipit quidem nulla pariatur sit aperiam ipsam asperiores nam accusantium, dolores soluta vero perferendis eveniet iusto commodi.

</div>
```

Comment: Ошибка в реализации. Щелчок назначается `div` нулевой высоты, а ожидается работа по клику `button`

Comment: Прошу прощения, не понял ответа.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как я уже отметил в комментарии, ошибка в логике. В вопросе назначается обработчик на `div` нулевой высоты. Ожидается работа с кнопкой.

```js
/** Функция, назначаемая кнопке - меняющая стиль .content, или иное */
function show_hide(){
  let content = document.getElementsByClassName('content');
  for (let index = 0; index < content.length; index++) {
    content[index].classList.toggle('active');
  }
}

let collapsible = document.getElementsByClassName('collapsible');
/* каждому элементу .collapsible назначается обработчик - функция выше */
for (let index = 0; index < collapsible.length; index++) {
  collapsible[index].addEventListener('click', show_hide);
}
```

```css
.content {
  display: none;
}
.content.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<button class="collapsible">clickme</button>
<div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quo optio illo quod enim suscipit quidem nulla pariatur sit aperiam ipsam asperiores nam accusantium, dolores soluta vero perferendis eveniet iusto commodi.</div>
```